# Unable to get Javascript file to run on page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm not good with script and I can't figure out what's going wrong with my execution.

The webpage is http://snmcsupport.com/map-js-test-page and it should be running a script that produces a clickable map.   The script itself is extremely long so I won't paste it here, but you can see it [if you click here](http://snmcsupport.com/wp-includes/js/app.js)

On my webpage, I have the markup necessary to run the script in the header

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js">
</script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.1.1/jquery.qtip.min.js">
</script>
```

On my webpage, I call the script

```
<div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://snmcsupport.com/wp-includes/js/app.js">
  </script>
</div>
```

But I still can't get the code to run?  The initial instructions from the developer also said:

> The last step is to initialize the map by making the following script calls:

```
<script>makeaClickableMap.initialize(<your-document-object-model-handle>);</script>
```

> where your-object-document-model handle can be anything actually:
>
> a jQuery object like $("#map")
>
> a Javascript Document Object Model like document.getElementById("map")
>
> or a simple string like "map"

but I can't figure out what that means.  If I try to put in the initialize command in my webpage I get a nasty cross-scripting error and it won't let me.

I'm running this on Wordpress using a Divi Child theme.

Comment: What about the use of WordPress jQuery files and embed qtip and Raphaël in the child theme? Are you enqueueing your js the right way with wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ...

Comment: Probably not...the developer of the script doesn't work directly with WP or Divi; I think he wrote it assuming it was being embedded directly into HTML.  Do I have to do the whole string:  wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
makeaClickableMap.initialize(<your-document-object-model-handle>);
            //this is the element that will --^
            //be used to contain your rendered map
```

The method `makeClickableMap.initialize()` expects you to pass it a reference of an HTML element where you want the map to appear.  Elements can be identified by

- their tag name (div, p, h1, etc.)
- a class name `<div class="className></div>`
- OR by id name, which I will demonstrate here:

Firstly, you;ll need an element with an ID associated with it, it should be placed inside the `<body>` tag:

`<div id="map"></div>`

underneath this tag, but still within the body tag, you'll need to include the `makeClickableMap.initialise` call and pass in the ID of this `<div>`:

```
<!-- Javascript solution: -->
<script>
  makeaClickableMap.initialize(document.getElementById('map'));
</script>
<!-- notice that the id is just 'map' here -->
```

An alternative to the Javscript solution above is using jQuery as follows (you'll still need the div with the ID):

```
<!-- jQuery solution: -->
<script>
  makeaClickableMap.initialize($('#map'));
</script>
<!-- notice the ID is prefixced with a '#' character-->
```

Comment: If I do that, I get "Request denied by WatchGuard Firewall.

Reason: IPS detected for "WEB Cross-site Scripting -32/Web Attack"

Please contact your administrator for assistance"

Comment: post a jsfiddle up if you can

Comment: Ok, the second one avoided the cross-scripting error but then I get an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < and an Uncaught ReferenceError

Comment: make sure you are cloing your script tags properly, check your `<script>` tags close with `</script>` (notice the forward slash)

Comment: I think it was because I had the <!-- jQuery solution: --> in there.  But now I'm back to getting the cross-site scripting error.  Is that because I'm trying to hyperlink to a URL with a parameter?  I have all the links in the JS to jump to snmcsupport.com/state-lo-results?state=[Statenamehere]

Comment: I got it to work; there was a firewall at work blocking me getting the scrip setup right.  Also, I had a typo in the initial script code.